# Advanced coupon and product pricing in opencart

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x

I have got couple of strange requirements for a shopping cart which is developed on Opencart 2.0.1.1 framework.

It would be really helpful if someone can guide me in this development

1. Is there any way I can show different product prices per country. For example if one product costs 10$ in USA, I want the same product to be of 15$ in UK.
2. Is there any way I can make user use one coupon to avail different discount rates for different products.  For example discount on product A is 1$ , then discount on Product B is 6$ but with same coupon code

Help is really appreciated. This is a quick requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this open cart extension for advanced coupon combinations,

```
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6240
```